# should I create instace fields for widgets in activity?

Tags: android, android-widget

As a novice device developer working on a inherited Adnroid project, I am wondering if its style of storing widgets in instance fields is a good practice.

The way this program is written, the `Activity.onCreate` , after calling `setContentView`, calls `findViewById` for each widget and assigns it instance fields. In other methods it calls `getText`, `setEnabled`, etc.

Is this considered best practice in the Android world? I mean leaning towards calling `findViewById` when needed, but wanted to find out how it is typically done.

Any good resources of well-written Android Apps (as against tutorials)?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `findViewById` could seem faster (I think it is just a placebo). I call it just once, from `onCreate` and assign it to either fields or local variables, depending on the situation. I think the reason for calling `findViewById` just once is because it is less verbose than executing that method every time it is needed.

Also, that's the way it is usually done. Just take a look at apps like the iosched app (which is written by Android engineers at Google) and you will see it how things are usually done by the most experienced developers.